# Magento 1.9.2.0 - Permissions Issue with Ajax Loader

Tags: php, ajax, magento

We've discovered a major new issue in Magento 1.9.2.0 related to the permissions updates. When a user is given manually set permissions - even if every single permission box is checked, the ajax loader fails to 'complete' and does not remove the loading spinner when the data is received. (But the data is received and drawn to the page). However, it works fine when the user has the catch-all 'all permissions' setting in their role.

I'm about to dig into this to see if I can find a solution, but tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I traced this down to a new incompatibility, specifically with the [Bubble Launcher](https://github.com/jreinke/magento-admin-launcher) ajax functionality. Because Magento now DENIES access to admin page controllers by default, the Bubble Launcher was making a failed Ajax call. However, since this was hooked into Magento's Prototype ajax system, it was leaving an incomplete ajax request in the queue. Because of this, the javascript that is supposed to remove the loader spinner failed because it only removes the spinner when the remaining ajax counter is 0.

Editing app/code/community/Bubble/Launcher/controllers/Adminhtml/Bubble/LauncherController.php to add:

```php
/**
 * Check is allowed access to action
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return true;
}
```

should fix the problem.